# Why doesn't CreateFile on C: increment the handle count for C:?

Tags: windows, winapi

I use CreateFile API to c: and get handle and then open winobj go to C: (the symbolicLink which point to the device) and check the handle count it says 0 now why is that (I don't close the handle in the meantime so why is that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:` is a symbolic link to something like `\Device\HarddiskVolume2`.  When you call `CreateFile` on `C:` you are actually opening a handle to `\Device\HarddiskVolume2`.

You are not opening a handle to the symbolic link, so the symbolic link has a handle count of zero.

Thus Object Manager symbolic links work like file system symbolic links.  Operations on the link are actually applied to the target, and different APIs are required to manipulate the link itself.